# Ошибка модуль не имеет атрибута entry_set. (DJANGO)

Tags: python, django

Я создаю сайт в котором пользователи могут писать и просматривать свои записи. На главной страницы находятся темы при переходе на них должен открыться динамический url с записями к этой теме. Но при переходе на любую запись мне выдаётся ошибка - type object 'Description' has no attribute 'entry_set'.

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Topic, Description


def index(request):
    topic = Topic.objects.all
    context = {'topic': topic}
    return render(request, 'Menu/Menu.html', context)


def description(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    description = Description.entry_set.all
    context = {'description': description, 'topic': topic}
    return render(request, 'Menu/Description.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models


class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class Description(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Descriptions'

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.text) > 10:
            return f'{self.text[:10]}...'
        else:
            return self.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Я просто заменил строку

```
description = Description.entry_set.all
```

в **views.py** под имя моего модуля `description = topic.description_set.all`. 
Так как я делал по книге я не понял что `entry_set` это не одна функция.